# How do I add a "ratings" box to a page?

Tags: 2010

This is my first time working with SharePoint. I have a new SharePoint 2010 Enterprise image, I've enabled the ratings feature and pages/content can be rated by viewing them as a list as described in [this MS article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/enable-users-to-rate-content-HA101791797.aspx).

However, there's no visible way for users to rate the content from the page itself. I've looked through the available web parts that the online editor offers me, and none of them seem to include this feature.

I'd be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in many ways:
1) if you use a custom webpart you can read the field from the list and create you object AverageRating
2) if you use a pagelayout you can use the control averagerating passing the guid of the field
3) using xslt